# How can I find the user's home dir in a cross platform manner, using C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, home-directory

How can I find the user's home directory in a cross platform manner in C++? i.e. /home/user in Linux, C:\Users\user\ on Windows Vista, C:\Documents And Settings\user\ on Windows XP, and whatever it is that Macs use. (I think it's /User/user)

Basically, what I'm looking for is a C++ way of doing this (example in python)

```
os.path.expanduser("~")
```

Comment: Cross-platform, you can't. Standard C++ has no such functionality.

Comment: Check my answer, there is a cross-platform way: you implement it using `#ifdef` :D

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910377/get-home-directory-in-linux-c

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to completely hide the Windows/Unix divide with this one (unless, maybe, Boost has something).

The most portable way would have to be `getenv("HOME")` on Unix and concatenating the results of `getenv("HOMEDRIVE")` and `getenv("HOMEPATH")` on Windows.

Comment: +1 This is more or less what Qt does in `QDir::homepath()` does: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdir.html#homePath. Probably check their source, too.

Comment: Note really. QT apparently returns `CSIDL_PROFILE`. And on my PC, that's a different directory. (`%HOMEDRIVE%` is on the fileserver, `CSIDL_PROFILE` isn't.)

Comment: @MSalters: just checked the source of my slightly dated Qt installation: on Windows, checks "HOME", "USERPROFILE", "HOMEDRIVE". On Unix, just tries "HOME". If not set, returns the root path.

Comment: Updated doclink for `QDir::homePath()` http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#homePath

Comment: Is that a way to get the real home before any setting HOME= to some other value ?

Comment: @Bionix1441 what do you mean?

Comment: I mean if I want to get the environment variable without taking into consideration the fact that on some shells it might has been set differently. Because if I set the home to /foo I will get /foo and this is not the real home directory

Comment: @Bionix1441 I still don't understand you. In the first sentence you are talking about getting the variable, while in the second you are talking about setting it without clearly indicating what order things are happening, or who's changing HOME, or why.

Comment: I mean that this will give you the environment variable, not the 'real'. The user might change it.

Comment: Why is this deliberately obfuscated code? There is no requirement in the question to protect against reverse engineering, so why make it unreadable?

Answer (score 24):

This **is possible**, and the best way to find it is to study the source code of `os.path.expanduser("~")`, it is really easy to replicate the same functionality in C.

You'll have to add some `#ifdef` directives to cover different systems.

Here are the rules that will provide you the HOME directory

- Windows: env `USERPROFILE` or if this fails, concatenate `HOMEDRIVE`+`HOMEPATH`
- Linux, Unix and OS X: env `HOME` or if this fails, use [`getpwuid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpwuid) ([example code](https://github.com/ehsan/ogre/blob/master/Samples/Browser/src/FileSystemLayerImpl_OSX.cpp#L46))

Important remark: **many people are assuming that `HOME` environment variable is always available on Unix but this is not true**, one good example would be OS X.

On OS X when you run an application from GUI (not console) this will not have this variable set so you need to use the getpwuid().

Comment: why would I try userprofile in the first place and if it fails then use homedrive and homepathh

Answer (score 2):

The home directory isn't really a cross-platform concept.  Your suggestion of the root of the profile directory (%USERPROFILE%) is a fair analogy, but depending what you want to do once you have the directory, you might want one of the Application Data directories, or the user's My Documents.  On UNIX, you might create a hidden ".myapp" in the home directory to keep your files in, but that's not right on Windows.

Your best bet is to write specific code for each platform, to get at the directory you want in each case.  Depending how correct you want to be, it might be enough to use env vars: HOME on UNIX, USERPROFILE or APPDATA (depending what you need) on Windows.

On UNIX at least (any Windows folks care to comment?), it's usually good practice to use the HOME environment variable if it's set, even if it disagrees with the directory specific in the password file.  Then, on the odd occasion when users want all apps to read their data from a different directory, it will still work.