# Finding my home directory in C/Unix

Tags: c, unix, directory, chdir, home-directory

I wrote a shell and whenever user gives an argument like cd -blabla it changes directory to bla bla.But when I enter cd I want it to go to my home directory.Assigning my home directory is easy.I just wrote whereis home to terminal to find my home directory but I can change my home directory.If I enter my adress into the function chdir() manually then it will always change to that directory.How can I find the most updated home directory in C?(which changes everytime I change my home directory)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910377/get-home-directory-in-linux-c)

Comment: What "most updated home directory" means ??? Home directory is not something that changes frequently, it is usually considered as constant over time. Anyway, either you can get the `HOME` environment variable or read `passwd` db to get the user dir entry.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at `pwd.h`. You can get information about a user by the UID or the name.

Example by id

```
struct passwd *info = getpwuid(1000);
```

Change 1000 to the UID you need. You could use getuid() defined in unistd.h 
to get the current user.

The field

```
info->pw_dir
```

Contains the home path of the user.