# Why is snprintf not reading after %s?

Tags: c, c-strings

I was trying to write a program that checks out if a location exists under the **/home/user directory**. To do that, I had to get the username with the `whoami` command and add the output of it to the buffer to use the `locate` command.

However, even though the `snprintf` read the `whoami` command, it didn't read the rest. I made a couple of searches and came to a result that `NULL` may not be terminated at the end of the string. Nevertheless, I couldn't find out how to terminate it manually. I am not sure what the problem is, so, here I am.

Here is the code for a better demonstration of my issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>
    
char *readFile(char *);
bool check();
    
bool check() {
    char path[200] = { 0 };
    
    snprintf(path, 200, "/home/%s/.example", readFile("whoami"));
    
    char lll[300] = { 0 };
    
    snprintf(lll, 300, "locate %s", path);
    
    char *buffer = readFile(lll);
    
    if (strcmp(buffer, path) == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

char *readFile(char cmd[200]) {
    char cmd1[99999] = { 0 };
    system("touch cmd");  
    snprintf(cmd1, 99999, "%s >> cmd", cmd);
    system(cmd1); 
        
    FILE *f = fopen("cmd", "rt");
    assert(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long length = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
    buffer[length] = '\0';
    fread(buffer, 1, length, f);
    fclose(f);
    system("rm cmd");
    return buffer;
}
    
int main() {
    int x = check();
    
    if (x == 1)
        printf("There is a location like that");
    else
        printf("There isn't");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should be using `getuid()` with `getpwuid()` to find the username and home directory, instead of that mess.

Comment: You can ensure a string that was prevented from overflowing a buffer is terminated, by writing a terminator to its last element: `path[199] = 0;`. However *"The `snprintf` function always stores a terminating null character, truncating the output if necessary."* It is `strncpy()` and `strncat()` which might not.

Comment: what is the result of `readFile("whoami")`? this seems like a problem trivially solvable using a debugger

Comment: @Shawn Thank you for the suggestion! Can you give a source that illustrates its usage or documentation?

Comment: Do you mean me? Please see [`snprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/snprintf-snprintf-snprintf-l-snwprintf-snwprintf-l). Oh, you edited the request!

Comment: @Chase it is 'eggman' which is my username in linux mint

Comment: @OmerErbilgin properly null terminated?

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, so its just all about terminating the null. But how am I going to terminate null to the end of a buffer which is different from a char array.

Comment: The return value from `fread` tells you how many data items were read (of the size requested). If it's text that needs to be terminated, you are using the wrong reading function. `fread` is intended for use with binary data, although it is sometimes used to read an entire text file into a buffer for analysis.

Comment: @WeatherVane Never thought about that, thanks for your answer and time! By the way, may I ask a recommendation for 'fread' if you dont mind.

Comment: My previous link posted has an index of functions.

Comment: See the man pages and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910377/get-home-directory-in-linux

Comment: If you want the output of the `whoami` command, just use `popen`, that is much simpler and safer than mucking around with temporary files. In addition, you can't assume the current home directory or default home directory is `/home/USERNAME`. The system administrator may use a different scheme. To get the current home directory you should read the `HOME` environment variable: `const char * homedir = getenv("HOME");`

Comment: @HAL9000 Thanks for your contribution to my question but my main aim is to use the snprintf() without separating strings while combining them together.

Comment: @OmerErbilgin, yes I understand you want to know why `snprintf` doesn't give the result you expected. But my comment is also for other users. Somebody could use your code as example on how to get current homedir.

Comment: You could use `popen` in `readFile()` instead of creating a temporary file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `whoami` command prints out the name of the current user, termintated by a newline. Reading back the file `cmd` into `buffer` will include that same newline character.

The `path` string will then be `"/home/USERNAME\n/.example"`. Trying to execute
`locate /home/USERNAME\n/.example` will probably confuse the `system` function.

The solution should then be to strip away the last newline in `readFile`.

Comment: Great! I solved the problem by using fflush(stdout) after adding the string that holds home path. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems in your `readFile` function:

- the name is misleading, it should be `runCommand` or something equivalent.
- you append the command output to the `cmd` file. This will cause unexpected results if the `cmd` file exists before you run your program. You should instead write:

  ```
  snprintf(cmd1, 99999, "%s > cmd", cmd);
  ```
- the command output probably has a trailing newline. You should trim the output.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readFile(const char *cmd) {
    /* construct the command */
    size_t size = 4 + strlen(cmd) + 1;
    char *cmd1 = malloc(size);
    assert(cmd1);
    snprintf(cmd1, size, "%s > cmd", cmd);

    /* run the command */
    system(cmd1);
    free(cmd1);
        
    /* read the output file */
    FILE *f = fopen("cmd", "rt");
    assert(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    long length = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *buffer = malloc(length + 1);
    buffer[length] = '\0';
    fread(buffer, 1, length, f);
    fclose(f);
    unlink("cmd");

    /* trim trailing white space from the output */
    while (length > 0 && isspace((unsigned char)buffer[length - 1])) {
        buffer[--length] = '\0';
    }
    /* trim leading white space from the output */
    size_t i = 0;
    while (isspace((unsigned char)buffer[i]) {
        i++;
    }
    if (i > 0) {
        memmove(buffer, buffer + i, length - i + 1);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Linux has a shortcut for your home directory ("~"), the whole "whoami"/"getuid" mess can be avoided by just using:

```
char *buffer = readFile("locate ~/.example");
```

You will still potentially have to trim off trailing newline and/or CR characters, perhaps with:

```
strtok(buffer,"\r\n\t ");
```

Or better yet, as @chqrlie suggests below.

Comment: Re *"Since Linux has a shortcut for your home directory ("~"),"*: Is it shell dependent (e.g. [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)) or not?

Comment: That may be correct, but a more universal solution would be to use "$HOME", which is defined under all shells.

Comment: @SGeorgiades Completely correct. I was just a beginner on C & bash, well I still am, so wasn't aware of that. To contribute, besides $HOME which returns more than the home directory, at least in ubuntu, I believe getenv() is also a cross platform method for getting standard paths.