# chdir(getenv("HOME") returns Bad address

Tags: c, chdir, getenv

```
      char *home = getenv("HOME");
      if (!strcmp(t->argv[0], "cd")) {
         if (!t->argv[1]) {
            chdir(home);
         }
         if (chdir(t->argv[1])) {
            perror(t->argv[1]);
         }
      }
```

what this is supposed to do is run the `cd` command with the provided argument, and if there is no argument provided then return to the home directory. if i call `cd` without an argument, `chdir` prints `"Bad address"`. i dont know why, considering i printed the value that `getenv("HOME")` returns and entered that path manually in my shell and it worked fine. why does it work when i provide the value but not when `getenv` provides it?

I also cant manually code a path for home either because it has to run on other machines. i need it to work with `getenv("HOME")`.

Comment: Sooo how do you know that `home` is not NULL? do you set the environment variable? Because it's not set if you don't set it.

Comment: You are calling chdir() to argv[1] even if it is NULL.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910377/get-home-directory-in-linux answer your question?

Comment: @dimich you were right, the first chdir worked fine, the second if should be an else if. see answer below, i credited you.

Answer (score 2):

i was being an idiot, as @dimich pointed out. the first chdir worked fine, but the second if statement should be an else if.

new code:

```
      char *home = getenv("HOME");
      if (!strcmp(t->argv[0], "cd")) {
         if (!t->argv[1]) {
            chdir(home);
         } else if (chdir(t->argv[1])) {
            perror(t->argv[1]);
         }
      }
```