# Opening a file in home directory

Tags: c++, file, unix

Say you have a program you run, and it has the following lines of code:

```
#include <fstream>
using std::fstream;

int main() {
     fstream someFile;
     someFile.open("~/someFile");

     if(!someFile.is_open()) {
          // Make the file
     }
}
```

I'm trying to open a file in the home directory (i.e. "~" on Unix devices). How could this be done? What I'm doing right now doesn't seem to work. Additionally, how can I make the file if it doesn't exist yet?

Note that this program can run from anywhere; not just home, but I need it to look for a file in the home directory.

Comment: Here's an old post: [Get home directory in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910377/get-home-directory-in-linux)

Comment: And here's a discussion about why we don't have a direct API for the home directory: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-proposals/c/8zH7v7ow5bQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open` has a second parameter: `openmode`, so you may want something like

```
someFile.open ("somefile", std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);
```

if you want to append.

For the home directory you can check `HOME` environment variable and `getpwuid`:

```
const char *homedir;

if ((homedir = getenv("HOME")) == NULL) {
    homedir = getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir;
}
```

Comment: What if you want to both read from and write to the file?

Comment: @zalanshah64 There are different flags you can set it to: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode