# How can I detect an existing directory in ~/ with stat in C?

Tags: c, bash, directory, mkdir, stat

If the directory `~/testdir` not exists, I want to create it.
Before the test, I create the directory `~/testdir`, but `stat` is not detecting it, and the program tries to create it once more.
I only has discovered this problem in `~/`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void main()
{
   system("mkdir ~/testdir");
   struct stat st = {0};
   if (stat("~/testdir", &st) == -1)
   {
       system("mkdir ~/testdir");
   }
}
```

Result:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/pi/testdir’: File exists
```

Comment: ~ (tilde) in `~/testdir` character is the current user's home directory in bash, but not for `stat`, use an absolute or a relative path but not a tilde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never test whether a file or directory exists before trying to do something with it.  That has an inherent "race condition": in between the test and the actual action, another process can come in and change things, causing the action to malfunction.  "Malfunction" doesn't just mean "fail", this kind of race bug can cause catastrophic damage to unrelated files and/or puncture security. It's such a common and severe bug that it has its very own [CWE](https://cwe.mitre.org/index.html) code, [CWE-367](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/367.html).

What you should do instead is *go ahead and do the thing you want to do* and see if that *failed*.  In this case, you should always try to create the directory, and if it fails with errno code EEXIST ("File exists") then ignore the error and proceed (but don't ignore any other errors).  The [`mkdir` shell utility](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkdir.1.html) has a `-p` option that makes it do exactly this, so your test program can be cut down to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   return system("mkdir -p ~/testdir") ? 1 : 0;
}
```

You can do the same thing directly in C using the [`mkdir` *function*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) plus an explicit check of errno:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int ensure_directory(const char *name, mode_t mode)
{
    if (mkdir(name, mode) == 0)
        return 0;
    if (errno == EEXIST)
        return 0;
    if (errno == ENOENT) {
        // parent directory doesn't exist, recurse up and create it
        // this is left as an exercise
    }
    perror(name);
    return 1;
}
```

However, this will not convert a leading `~` to the name of the user's home directory. In principle you could use [`wordexp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html) to do that part without invoking a shell, but it's enough extra work that I would probably stick with `system("mkdir -p ~/testdir")`, *as long as the name of the directory to create is hardcoded*.

If any part of `~/testdir` comes from user input (including config files) in your full program, then stuffing it into `system` becomes unsafe and you need to ask a new question about how to safely expand `~` and possibly also `$VARIABLE` without doing any of the other things `wordexp` does.

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation. I was not aware of the ``mkdir`` function in C.

Answer (score 2):

`~` is an alias that shell expands to your home directory. This is why it works inside `system` which runs the command in a shell. And why it doesn't work inside `stat` which does not do such expansion and is looking for a file called literally `~/testdir` under the current directory.

You need to get the home directory (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26696759/21105992) and build the path yourself.

Comment: That explains the problem. Now I see that it had been better to use **bash** to test if ''~/testdir'' excists

Comment: @EddySorngard It would have been better to get your home directory and use the `mkdir` function to create the directory and the `stat` function to test if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Since `stat` does not recognize `~/`, the problem could have been solved using **bash** to test before creating the directory

```
system("[ ! -d ~/testdir ] && mkdir ~/testdir")
```

Comment: This will work almost in any Bourne like shell today, except in the original AT&T `/bin/sh`.