# QImage save return false when using ~

Tags: c++, qt, qimage

I want to save a `QImage` in the user's home, I use `~/` but save() seems to not appreciate and return false without any message...
So

```
img->save("~/pict.jpg");
```

is not working and I'm looking for a glitch...

Comment: Is the missing closing quote in the code as well? It should be `save("~/pict.jpg");`

Comment: Is the `QImage::save` working when you specify another location? i.e. you've verified it is actually working and that the ~ that's the issue?

Comment: It works well with "./pict.jpg" so I guess ~ is guilty

Comment: @VBB ok good because sometimes it can be the JPG plugin isn't installed correctly which can cause `QImage::save` to return false since the format type isn't supported. That doesn't seem to be the case here. :)

Comment: @LucTouraille you're right, I might was looking  with the wrong keywords

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` is interpreted by the Shell, not by the operating system (or the C library, or the Qt library).

You need to get the user's home directory through `getenv("HOME")`, for instance. See also [How can I find the user's home dir in a cross platform manner, using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552416/how-can-i-find-the-users-home-dir-in-a-cross-platform-manner-using-c)

With Qt, you can use [QDir::homepath](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdir.html#homePath) to retrieve the user's home directory in a platform independent way.

Comment: That should have been obvious for me. Thank you Andreas!